# Application for united kingdom

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, casablanca

I have applied for a United Kingdom visit visa but I did not sign my application. I do not know if it will be rejected.

Is there any chance they will accept my application? I'm really tense about that so please advise me. What should I do?